# Puppet: ensure a file is empty

Tags: puppet

I would like to be sure that the motd file is empty. I would love to do like this:

```
file { "/etc/motd":
  ensure => empty
}
```

This obviously does not work.

Is there a simple way to ensure a file is empty instead using the "source" declaration and store an empty file in the file repository?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This ought to work just fine to ensure that the file does exist and contains nothing:

```
file { '/etc/motd':
  ensure => present,
  content => '',
}
```